# Git squashing a few commits

Tags: git, merge, rebase, squash

I'm facing a scenario wit git squash. I have a feature branch which has already around 70 commits. While I was adding commits, the master branch also had so many changes and because of that I had done several merges in this 70 commits. Now I want to merge to the master but before that i need to clean up the history by reducing to say ,30 commits. I tried direct squashing without rebase but i was getting lots of conflicts on files which I didnt work. So I thought I would rebase first to the latest master and then squash some of the commits. –, i.e not squashing all the commits into 1 single commit. This is what i tried:

1. git rebase to master( git rebase -i master)

I get conflicts on most of the commits and i try to solve it, and get all commits on top of the master branch. This is also a bit tricky as the master also had changes on the same files which I worked and sometimes when I solve the conflicts, the commit may look incorrect( as in the code may not be compilable).

Is there a better way to handle this situation ?

Comment: Unclear. Did you already merge to master? Or what?

Comment: No. I haven't . I want to merge it but before that i need to clean up the history by reducing to say ,30 commits. I tried direct squashing without rebase but i was getting lots of conflicts on files which I didnt work. So I thought I would rebase first to the latest master  and then squash some of the commits.

Comment: Next time you face a long-running project like this, consider rebasing on master every time you need changes from it, instead of merging master into your branch.

Comment: That is excellent! So do you want to squash successive sets of commits or just create the whole chain of commits from scratch?

Comment: @matt i want to squash successive set of commits. For eg commits from 5-10, 15-20 , 35-40 in the 70 commits.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, I learned it from this  :)

Comment: Then just rebase interactively to the first commit of the series and away you go.

Comment: @matt If I do that, i get all the individual commits in the merge commits in between my original commits in the feature branch in the interactive rebase window. Is there a way to drop this ? Or should i skip all those commits while rebasing ?

Comment: Ah, okay, so you periodically reverse-merged from the main branch into the feature branch? So what is it that you'd like to do about that _now_ during the cleanup?

Comment: Is there a better way to do it? Say for example, rebasing to the first commit on the feature branch or even an older commit on the master branch, then taking all my commits on top of it and finally do one merge of the master to the feature?